# "Build error: Build failed with 4 error(s) UnityEngine.Debug:LogErrorFormat (string,object[])" while building using Play Asset Delievery in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, assets

Hi I am building a game using Unity. The problem came when I tried uploading the .aab file and it said file size greater than  150mb can't be accepted.

I used Play Asset delivery to overcome this problem. I created the asset bundle as per this [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Workflow.html) and followed the instructions as per this link to build the file as per this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-unity). But while building the file it said API level 31 is required. It tried to download it automatically but failed. So as per this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Qay9h14swM&ab_channel=SmartPenguins-GameDev) using command prompt I manually downloaded the API levels and overcome this problem. But while building the app bundle I am getting "Compilation failed error" the screenshot of which I am attaching [image: Compilation failed error]

ALso later build failed with 4 errors comes in and the screenshot of the console is here: [image: Console screenshot]

This is what the console message looks like:

```
Build error: Build failed with 4 error(s)
UnityEngine.Debug:LogErrorFormat (string,object[])
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.BuildToolLogger:DisplayErrorDialog (string) (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/BuildTools/BuildToolLogger.cs:95)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.AndroidBuilder:Build (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions) (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/BuildTools/AndroidBuilder.cs:205)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.AppBundleBuilder:BuildAndroidPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions) (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/BuildTools/AppBundleBuilder.cs:179)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.AppBundlePublisher:Build (Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.BuildTools.AppBundleBuilder,Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.AppBundlePublisher/AppBundleBuildSettings) (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/AppBundlePublisher.cs:175)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.AppBundlePublisher:Build () (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/AppBundlePublisher.cs:139)
Google.Android.AppBundle.Editor.Internal.AppBundleEditorMenu:BuildAndroidAppBundle () (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.android.appbundle/Editor/Scripts/Internal/AppBundleEditorMenu.cs:66)
```

I tried to solve this issue by googling but regarding Play Asset delivery I am not finding any great articles.

Any help will really be appreciated as I am stuck in this problem for the past 2 days. If you need any more help please let me know

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trials I used Unity version 2021.2.5f1 and check the "Seperate base Apk base" and it has worked. Hope this might help anyone in future